# Remove a file from git locally, but not on remote

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file full of tests that fail locally, because my local environment doesn't have some software installed. The tests succeed on our continuous integration system, and I never touch the code being tested, so I would like to remove this file locally so that tests pass locally, but not remove the file from the remote server. Is this possible using git's ignoring mechanisms?

Comment: You can remove a file locally and as long as you don't say git rm, it will not remove the file from the repository. However, it is not without its risks.

As for the gitignore, the gitignore is there to prevent certain files from being committed, so it probably will not work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewFan: the next commit the file will be reomved iirc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try git magic here (that is generally considered harmful)

You just delete file with `rm` (not *git* rm)

And then mark the file being deleted as unchanged

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```

<sup>(*Though I haven't check that following commits will not break your code*)</sup>